# Python DictWriter /n

Tags: python, csv

I am using the following code and it works well except for the fact that my code spits out on to a CSV file from Excel and it skips every other line. I have googled the csv module documentation and other examples in [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652806/csv-write-skipping-lines-when-writing-to-csv) and I found that I need to use DictWriter with the lineterminator set at '\n'. My own attempts to write it into the code have been foiled.

So I am wondering is there a way for me to apply this(being the lineterminator) to the whole file so that I do not have any lines skipped? And if so how?

Here is the code:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import csv

page = urllib2.urlopen('http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=F%20Key%20Statistics').read()

f = csv.writer(open("pe_ratio.csv","w"))
f.writerow(["Name","PE"])

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
all_data = soup.findAll('td', "yfnc_tabledata1")
f.writerow([all_data[2].getText()])
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by 'skips every other line'?  Can you give an example input, the output you're getting and the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open your file with the right options for the `csv.writer` class to work correctly. The module has universal newline support internally, so you need to turn off Python's universal newline support at the file level.

For Python 2, [the docs say](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer):

> If `csvfile` is a file object, it must be opened with the `'b'` flag on platforms where that makes a difference.

For Python 3, [they say](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer):

> If `csvfile` is a file object, it should be opened with `newline=''`.

Also, you should probably use a `with` statement to handle opening and closing your file, like this:

```
with open("pe_ratio.csv","wb") as f: # or open("pe_ratio.csv", "w", newline="") in Py3
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    # do other stuff here, staying indented until you're done writing to the file
```

Answer (score 0):

First, since Yahoo provides an API that returns CSV files, maybe you can solve your problem that way? For example, [this URL](http://biz.yahoo.com/p/csv/330conamed.csv) returns a CSV file containing prices, market cap, P/E and other metrics for all stocks in that industry. There is some [more information in this Google Code project](https://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/csvCompanyDownload).

Your code only produces a two-row CSV because there are only two calls to `f.writerow()`. If the only piece of data you want from that page is the P/E ratio, this is almost certainly not the best way to do it, but you should pass to `f.writerow()` a tuple containing the value for each column. To be consistent with your header row, that would be something like:

```
f.writerow( ('Ford', all_data[2].getText()) )
```

Of course, that assumes that the P/E ratio will always be second in the list. If instead you wanted all the statistics provided on that page, you could try:

```
# scrape the html for the name and value of each metric
metrics = soup.findAll('td', 'yfnc_tablehead1')
values = soup.findAll('td', 'yfnc_tabledata1')

# create a list of tuples for the writerows method
def stripTag(tag): return tag.text
data = zip(map(stripTag, metrics), map(stripTag, values))

# write to csv file
f.writerows(data)
```